# How to force download of an Angular PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing an Angular PWA. Is there a way to show a popup to users who are accessing my app from a browser to save it as an app on the home screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Web App Install Banners](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/).

When your app meets the criteria, the browser will show the web app install banner prompting the user if they want to add the app to their homescreen.

In Chrome, the current criteria are

1. your app must have a Web App Manifest
2. your app must have a Service Worker installed
3. your app must be served over secure HTTPS (except when you are accessing it on localhost)
4. your app is visited at least twice, with at least five minutes between visits

See linked article for more details about how to make your app addable to the home screen.

Comment: @Onno - Just a quick tip: In the future when making an edit to an answer based on the text at an included link, note that that's where the correction/text comes from in your edit summary. You got one reject on your suggestion because the reviewer thought you were trying to address the author of the post, not just fix a typo.

Comment: Particularly note the `Deferring or cancelling the prompt` section. You can catch Chrome's automatic user prompt and show your own UI for the user to trigger.

Comment: For more details see this link: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/turn-your-angular-app-into-a-pwa-in-4-easy-steps-543510a9b626

Answer (score -1):

In a newer version of angular, They automatically give prompt to the user for add to home screen in the mobile device. if your application have service worker,manifest file & in the secured connection

Comment: What If I need to trigger this popup on some event?